# How to install dual Blender version

Tags: installation

Still not looking fine with 2.8.

**What i have tried so far -**

1. I have 2.79 b version installed and when i installed the new version 2.8 it over lapped. Then i reinstalled again the older version.
2. I created a folder in c:\Program files\ Blender foundation (Name 2.8) and installed 2.8 in the that path but still it over lapped the previous version.
3. I created a folder in D: drive (Name 2.8) installed 2.8 in the that path but still it over lapped the previous version.

I can download the zip file and use but i want to install dual version. Any suggesition how to install.

Comment: Is there any problem that you don't want use the zipped version? They are almost the same thing, but the installation will register the Blender thorough system.

Comment: @Hikariztw As for other software Photoshop, coreldraw different version we can use. Same way i want to use Blender a lower and higher version

Comment: But the zipped version provide the solution: I have 6 version with 2.79b and 2.80alpha, 2.80beta, and 2.80 stable. You just open the execution file and everything will be the same. Also, the setting is not the same in 2.79b and 2.80